# Android start intent to view apk

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

In my application I am downloading and saving an apk to the SDcard and then I want to start the installation of the apk. I'm using the following code to attempt this:

```
Intent intent =new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

But when I do this it tells me there is no activity to start the intent. What I am attempting to do is install a new update for the currently running application. How do I start an Intent to run an apk file?

Comment: Would be where ever the apk was saved. Eg. /sdcard/test.apk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try using `Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))` instead of `Uri.parse(file)`?

Comment: Hey... Buddy Thanks But After Install The APK My Application is Close How to Prevent It. I Want To Re-Open It Again

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent =new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
activity.startActivity(intent);
```