# Auto Update APK version on Android Phone

Tags: android, auto-update

If a user downloads my app *(a .apk file)* onto their android phone from the market place,

1. Where does the .apk file end up on their phone?
2. When they're running my application, if I detect that there is a new later version of the application available is it possible to **from within the application that they're running** download the latest version off an ftp link (I can programmatically do that now) and then replace the existing .apk that they're now running with the newer version. [Not sure about this one at all.]
3. Is the existing application all in memory when it's being run, so that when i download the new version, I can delete its apk file without it being locked up and replace it with the later build and then restart the app?

What's the best way to handle this scenario? I have an app where I want to ensure that users are on the latest version before they use it.

Comment: how many questions are there ? i have already tried to format this but still its looking bit difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Apps are stored in `/data/app` see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed.

IMHO, You should let the market manage updates for you, there's no need to bother doing anything by hand and as an user I would be "angry" if some app start downloading stuff on my phone without my consent, especially when abroad (some users are paying their datas).

Comment: I would presumably prompt the user, asking for permission to download the latest update before I actually did the download. It wouldn't, under any circumstances, be mandatory for you to download the update at that given point in time; you could opt out of it, so to speak.  So is it possible to download the new apk and replace the one that's currently running in the /data/app if the user agrees to that download?  I'd prefer to do this over dumping them into the market, but I can do that if the its not feesible to do the above.

Comment: I don't know about the feasibility, my point was don't bother, the market can do that for you, and will probably do it better. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308473/auto-update-for-private-android-apps for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

If this user has rooted phone, you may use code provided in this answer: [Android silent apk update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267081/android-silent-apk-update/25896543#25896543).

If not, user has to be prompted, and you may start an activity with an intent (as usual), but also, before calling startActivity(intent), call intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(...)).