# How to install .apk file without any prompt silently

Tags: android

I am trying to launch the app that will be installed on android tablet(Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.0) which is NOT ROOTED.
Once it is installed, it should be auto-updated as soon as I update the .apk either on my own server or on google play. I read many postings about this and tried the following ways.

1. I tried the way below.
   I downloaded the .apk from my server. Then, tried to install it without any prompt 
   installProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c pm install -r " + filePath);

[Android silent apk update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267081/android-silent-apk-update)
This way does not work. I think it is because my device is not ROOTED. My company does not allow me to ROOT the device.

2. I uploaded my .apk in google play and installed the app through google play on tablet. Then, I changed the code and updated .apk and uploaded it to google play. Even if google play republished my updated app, it does not automatically update my .apk...
3. I also tried to put the user-permission INSTALL PACKAGE as someone wrote.
   I can't even place this since the app I am working on is not System App.

Would you please advise me of how to handle this issue?  I have seen Tinder app update by itself without me pressing anything. There was no update notification I have ever seen.

Thanks,

Thank you all for my questions.

Then, isn't there any ways that I can make this app System App without ROOTing my device?

Comment: This app really behaves like a malware.

Comment: Is that even allowed?

Comment: I have seen Tinder update by itself....I am sure there is a way...

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/202297/how-to-disable-automatic-app-updates-in-android/

Comment: @John3328 No. By default, if you are on `Wifi` and `Charging`, Google play will automatically update your apps.

Comment: Depending on the device settings, apps may be allowed to update automatically as long as their required permissions do not change.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Those updates are done through Google Play though.

Comment: @JaredBurrows, True, but that's probably why Tinder is allowed to do it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, then, what kinds of required permissions should I not change? Any ideas?

Comment: @John3328 Apps can only update automatically if the permissions are exactly the same as the ones the user already accepted.  And even then, the user may disable automatic updates.  See [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/202297/how-to-disable-automatic-app-updates-in-android).

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede, thank you so much advice. Actually, no user is allowed to disable automatic updates because this app is going to be Kiosk mode. The app is going to be locked as home and the user won't do anything not even go to setting since I will block them completely.

Comment: @JaredBurrows: I think you have done something like that before. I actually tried auto-update as I stated on my question above. On my second update, the only thing I changed was 'VersionCode' and 'Version Name' with all other permission the same as the version 1. However, I didn't notice google play autoupdated my version 2 after one day. Would you please advise me if Google Play does autoupdate this?

Comment: @John3328 I have said twice in my comments that it is Google Play.

Comment: @JaredBurrows:thank you so much.. I will try it with my tablet charged and wifi-connected. I really hope this works.

Comment: @John3328 Last time(Look at your Google Play settings): 1) Android device must be **charging**. 2) Wifi should be connected(internet). 3) The App should have auto-update enabled.

Comment: @JaredBurrows:Thank you so much for clarification. I am testing right now and I will keep you updated to see if it works. I am following all of your instructions above.

Answer (score 0):

Only system apps can install, update or uninstall applications.
`android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` is only for system applications.

Comment: I know...Then, should I make this app System app? Isn't there any ways to do it?

Comment: @John3328 No, you wouldn't/couldn't publish it to Google Play.

Comment: As a 3rd party developer, you cannot install a "system app" on a secured device unless you have broken the security model, ie, "rooted" it.