# Check for updates to app, inside that app on Android

Tags: android, notifications, google-play, updates

Does the android market (or Google Play as it's now) offer a way for an app to check if it's updatable?

It seems to take very long for people to notice (or care) to update their apps. I'd like to show some "Update available" notify inside my app.

I could just have some file on a webserver stating the latest version. But this has the obvious chance of pissing people of if they click the "update available" button and are then taken to market which doesn't yet have the update.

So is there some nice API or other brilliant ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Android Market takes a very good care of updating your application. Users are notified as soon as your update is available, and if they decide to ignore the notification, it's their decision.

If you are looking for alternative methods of updating your application, I'd suggest to check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308473/auto-update-for-private-android-apps).

Answer (score 0):

No, Google Play store is a closed system and it does not expose an API to check version number since it takes care of updating installed apps whenever updates are available. However can be done by having a web service which keeps us updated on current version of android app on google play store and then compare the installed app version with the version we got from web service. Please have a look at https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-query/wikis/Service.wiki